# How to read email with proper rights in token

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to upgrade an application (it should fetch emails from a mailbox every few minutes) from Microsoft EWS deprecated API to the new Graph API, but I am facing some issues.

This is my class for the connector :

```
public class O365graphApiConnector {

  private final GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient;

  public O365graphApiConnector(String clientId, String username, String password) {

    final UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential =
        new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .build();

    final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider =
        new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(usernamePasswordCredential);

    graphClient=GraphServiceClient.builder()
        .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
        .buildClient();
  }

  public User getUserProfile() {
    return graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
  }

  public MessageCollectionPage getOutlookEmails() {
    return graphClient.me().messages().buildRequest().get();
  }

}
```

I am using `com.azure:azure-identity:1.4.2` and `com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:5.8.0`.

I build the connector, passing the `clientId`, `username` and `password`. I am able to call `getUserProfile` , and I am getting something, so the authentication "works".

However, I get a 404 when calling `getOutlookEmails` :

> SEVERE: Throwable detail:
> com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code:
> ResourceNotFound Error message: Resource could not be discovered.
>
> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages SdkVersion :
> graph-java/v5.8.0
>
> 404 : Not Found [...]

When I run this in debug mode and intercept the token, it seems to be OK though : I have a bunch of rights that my admin has given to the applicative account :

```
 "scp": "EWS.AccessAsUser.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite
 Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared MailboxSettings.ReadWrite User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadWrite profile openid email"
```

This is part of what we see on the admin side (more rights were added after the screenshot was taken) :

[image]

My understanding is that this should be enough to get access to the emails of the given mailbox programmatically, but apparently, it's not.

Any idea of what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, the technical "user" I am using didn't really have a mailbox (despite the user name being an email address.. that confused me).

It had been given the permissions on the given mailbox I am interested in though, so the fix is simply to select the mailbox/user before retrieving the messages :

```
public MessageCollectionPage getOutlookEmailsFor(String mailbox) {
  return graphClient.users(mailbox).messages().buildRequest().get();
}
```